# Reading c# combo box text and value?

Tags: c#, combobox

I wrote this code to save value and text into the combo box:

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
for (int i = 0; i < query.Count(); i++)
{
    item.Text = query[i].gaptitle1.ToString();
    item.Value = query[i].id.ToString();

    comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
 }
```

I want save my query two field into the combo box,first title field and second id field,i need id unique field for search in other my application,for example when i want to read the combo box data and value with this method:

```
listBox1.Visible = true;
listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox2.Text);
listBox2.Items.Add((comboBox2.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString());
```

With the above code, when the user fires the button combo box, I want text save into the list box 1 and id to save into the listbox2, but latest value shows.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie thanks my friend to pay attention to my problem,i read array date with two field ,id and title,id save into combo box value and title save into the combo box text,but when i read the data,i see save latest array value into the combo box item

Comment: No worries! My first comment was incorrect, as I hadn't read the whole question. You need to define `item` _inside_ your `for` loop, as you're currently just overwriting `item`'s properties each time the loop goes round, so you end up with a combo box containing a set of identical items (because they're all the same item)!

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie thanks for help me,please write your code into the post ,and i vote up your post

Comment: Done! I also included some advice based on my first (deleted) comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you should be defining `item` *inside* your `for` loop, as you're currently adding the same item to your `ComboBox` once for each result in your query, while also updating the item's text and value to match the current query result. At the end of the loop, you end up with a `ComboBox` full of identical items, all equal to the last item in your query. This is how your code *should* look:

```
for (int i = 0; i < query.Count(); i++)
{
    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
    item.Text = query[i].gaptitle1.ToString();
    item.Value = query[i].id.ToString();

    comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
 }
```

Just for tidiness/safety, I would recommend changing your "addition" code to this:

```
listBox1.Visible = true;
var selectedItem = (ComboboxItem)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
listBox1.Items.Add(selectedItem.Text);
listBox2.Items.Add(selectedItem.Value);
```

Firstly, if you know the selected item is a `ComboboxItem`, there's no point in using `as`. An explicit cast is clearer in intent. Secondly, it's safer to read your values straight out of your `ComboboxItem` rather than assuming that the `ComboBox`'s `Text` will always contain the bound item's `Text`.